# Enum to List<special> data

Tags: c#, list, enums

So I want to transfer enum to list. List definition is:

```
public class WritingList : ViewModelBase
{
    private int _enumgroup;
    public int EnumGroup
    {
        get { return _enumgroup; }
        set
        {
            if (_enumgroup != value)
            {
                _enumgroup = value;
                //NotifyPropertyChanged("LanguageName");
            }
        }
    }

    private byte[] _messagetosend;
    public byte[] Messagetosend
    {
        get { return _messagetosend; }
        set
        {
            if (_messagetosend != value)
            {
                _messagetosend = value;
                //NotifyPropertyChanged("CultureInfo");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My enum definition

```
enum ReadWrite
{
    Name,
    DateLastConfigured,
    NameLastConfiguredConfiguration,
    PCNameLastConfigured,
};
```

Now I like to add item into List

```
List<WritingDataList> data = new List<WritingDataList>();

data.Add(new WritingList() { EnumGroup = 1, Messagetosend = question1 });
```

Because I like to later compare it with if statement, to search the right one. Please for help. If any question please ask.

Comment: Currently you are not using your enum so the question is unclear. Why is `EnumGroup` an `int` and not a `ReadWrite`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but I *think* you're asking how to store an enum value as a property of an item in a list.

```
// Here's some example type definitions
public enum MyEnum {One, Two, Three};

public class MyClass : BaseClass {
    public MyEnum EnumValue {get;set;}
}

public class MyList : List<MyClass>


// Here's how you'd use them
public void DoStuff() {
    var list = new MyList();  // or new List<MyClass>();
    list.Add(
        new MyClass{ EnumValue = MyEnum.One },
        new MyClass{ EnumValue = MyEnum.Two }
    );

    foreach (var item in list) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.EnumValue.ToString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry for bad question. Code is bad written because I change it between to play how to implement exactly that what you show me now :) THANKS!